# php loops return array repeatedly from form

Tags: php, simplexml

$article is an array:

```
        $article= array();

        //values
        $article['title'] = $item->title;
        $article['url'] = $item->link;
        $article['description'] = $item->description;
```

These are obtained through an xml parse using simpleXML
when I submit the checkboxes (however many are ticked) I try to run for loops, foreach and even nests but it just prints array.

I have a form of checkboxes as such:

```
echo'<td><input type="checkbox" name="article[]" value="'.$article.'"><br>  </td>';
```

I fetch the results from the form like so:

```
   $value = $_POST['article'];
```

and then

```
  for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++)
    {
       echo "The row number  $value[$row]";
       echo '<br/>';

        for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++)
         {
          echo "$value[$row][$col]";

           echo '<br/>';

    }}
```

I thought it might have been a multidimensional associative array but getting nowhere with this.
I really could do with someone pointing out what I am doing wrong.

Solution found with Yordi's solution but also billyonecan for noting casting xml objects as string.

So my values should be
 //values

```
        $article['title'] = (string)$item->title;
        $article['url'] = (string)$item->link;
        $article['description'] = (string)$item->description;
```

before serialising.

Comment: if you are not sure how the array looks like, printing it like this always helps.

echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST['article']); echo "</pre>";

Comment: it looks like this:Array
(
    [0] => Array
    [1] => Array
    [2] => Array
)

Comment: So it seems your subarray items are converted into strings= "Array". When you read from XML you should convert to string, like this: $item->title.'' and then it will give you nice strings.

Comment: You also have a bug here: value="'.$article.'". I think this should be $article['title'] not just $article

Comment: I've got $item->title above haven't i? @Tom

Comment: @DOWmad In the echo at the top of your question you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't echo an array (as such, check the edit below) - that's what you're trying to do inside of your `checkbox` value. <s>You could create the indexes manually, and echo their corresponding values.</s>

As pointed out by @Yordi, you can [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) the array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="article[]" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($article)); ?>" />
```

and then [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize) it after posting it to the server:

```
foreach ($_POST['article'] as $a) {
    $value = unserialize($a);
    echo $value['title']; // url, description..
}
```

Comment: this! if you want to pas the array, you can call it just name='articles' and as value='<?php echo serialize($articles);?>'

in your $_POST script, you unserialize it, and tadaaa !

Comment: I'm getting more untadaaa sadly

Comment: @Yordi I get this warning  Warning: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Node no longer exists in save_article.php on line 11